# Sending TCP SYN packet with Boost::Asio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, tcp, boost-asio

Recently I began working with the Boost::Asio library (C++). I'm looking for a way to send a TCP SYN  message to a end destination. However I can't find any way of doing this, does somebody knows a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP stack usually deals with this, not your code. If you just call `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::connect()` on an appropriately constructed instance, you will cause a TCP SYN packet to be sent, along with the rest of the TCP handshake and session handling.

Update:

If you want to implement TCP yourself you will need to deal with more than just a TCP SYN, otherwise you're just writing code to attack systems with half-open connections. You need a raw socket and you need to construct the contents of the packet yourself. If you are doing this you should be able to RTFM to find out more.

Comment: It goes indeed about a half-open connection, first I want to look at how I can send a TCP SYN message and then look what the response is when the TTL is 0.